# Jstestdriver setup and teardown

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Does anyone know the syntax for setUp and tearDown functions/methods for JsTestdriver?  On their website they claim to be able to define it, but I can't get it right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I download the code and greped for "setUp" and discovered the following:

```
javascript/TestCaseBuilder.js:  if (typeof testCaseClass.prototype.setUp == 'undefined') {
javascript/TestCaseBuilder.js:    testCaseClass.prototype.setUp = function() {};
javascript/plugins/TestRunnerPlugin.js:    if (testCaseInstance.setUp) {
javascript/plugins/TestRunnerPlugin.js:      testCaseInstance.setUp();
```

And similar for "tearDown":

```
javascript/TestCaseBuilder.js:  if (typeof testCaseClass.prototype.tearDown == 'undefined') {
javascript/TestCaseBuilder.js:    testCaseClass.prototype.tearDown = function() {};
javascript/plugins/TestRunnerPlugin.js:      if (testCaseInstance.tearDown) {
javascript/plugins/TestRunnerPlugin.js:        testCaseInstance.tearDown();
```

So it seems that the setUp and tearDown functions are defined just like any other test function except that their name is 'setUp' and 'tearDown'. Their example was:

```
GreeterTest = TestCase("GreeterTest");

GreeterTest.prototype.testGreet = function() {
  var greeter = new myapp.Greeter();
  assertEquals("Hello World!", greeter.greet("World"));
};
```

And not knowing what level of js programmer you are, if you are not familiar with the 'prototype' key (because it has a very special meaning in javascript), then check out [these YUI vids](http://video.yahoo.com/watch/111585/1027823)

However, that seems like a really bad design decision because this way you can define only one setUp and tearDown function, so I feel like there's got to be a better way, but that's the best I could find.

And I agree that their documentation description of setUp, tearDown does not seem most intuitive.

And in case you are looking for other options as well, I am just starting to learn [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and am finding it satisfactory (though its docs are also lacking a little I think)